# Cannot find or open PDB file

Tags: visual-studio

I am building and running my project successfully, but when I try to set a breakpoint, Visual Studio tells me "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

When I open up the Modules window, I can see that for all of the .dll files in my project, the Symbol Status is "Cannot find or open the PDB file."

I'm very new to Visual Studio and C++ development in general, so any suggestions you have for me are very appreciated!

Comment: When you look in the build output folder for one of those DLLs, can you see the PDB file? If so, have you tried manually pointing the debugger to it? If you can't find a PDB file on your disk either, then you may have inadvertently turned off the option that generates these. Check your project's properties to make sure. Aside from that, we're going to need more information if we are going to help you; this is a pretty broad problem description.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I can see the PDB files, so I'm definitely still generating them. How would I manually point the debugger to them?

Comment: Did you delete the PDB and rebuild? Are they really generated or might it be an old version just lying there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had Just-My-Code enabled while using a file in release. Turning off JMC fixed the issue. Thanks!